# When i press "edit with idle" py 3.6 it never opens up the file

Tags: python-3.x

6 x64 on windows 10 and my edit with idle button will not work i have searched up on google but no avail will some please help?
Many thanks Matt!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Try renaming the file to something that doesn't have the name of a python module or import